# KeepAlives and MaxConnectionIdle for bidirectional GRPC streams

Tags: grpc, amazon-eks, keep-alive, grpc-java, nlb

so for context I have an issue where my GRPC server is not aware of outstanding GRPC bidi streams being closed. This is because idle connections are closed by NLBs in AWS without notifying either the client or server (see [here](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/lesson-learned-from-a-nlb-connection-timeout-2c672e59e197)).

I've attempted to solve this issue by setting my GRPC keep alive setting to less than the idle connection timeout. However we are still see the same problem where the server thinks that a connection is still active. I understand how KeepAlives and the MaxConnectionIdle setting work for unary RPC calls, but how do they work for bidi streams? At what point is there considered to be "no outstanding RPCs" so an idle connection can be closed? I attempted to use `permitKeepAliveWithoutCalls` but this did not fix my issue, so I feel like there is something I am not understanding here. Thanks for any help!